# Why addPolygon change position image - phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a problem when I use addPolygon. Polygon change position image. When I turn on debug I see images, and new shape draw in center. Second problem I don't now why image and shape Polygon is different. How fix this problem ? I not seen problem when I use addRectangle. Image and new shape is corect in tile 70px x 70px.

```
function create() {
...
groups.tile = game.add.group();
groups.tile.enableBody = true;
groups.tile.enableBodyDebug = true;
groups.tile.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.P2JS;
groups.tile.collideWorldBounds = false;
...

var obj = groups.tile.create((x * map.width) - (map.width / 2), (y * map.height) - (map.height / 2), spriteName, numberTile);
obj.body.static = true;
obj.body.fixedRotation = true;
obj.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
obj.body.clearShapes();

var myPolygonArray= [ [0,0], [0,70], [70,70], [70,46], [25,46],  [25,0]];
obj.body.addPolygon({}, myPolygonArray);
}
```

Example:

a) [image]  b) [image]  c)  [image]

If someone found it there any solution?

Comment: try to set sprite anchore point 

sprite.anchore.setTo(0.5,0.5);

Comment: It is a kind solution. After using SETTO properly shifted graphics, but there is still 1 millimeter of non-compliance.
I also changed positions added myPolygonArray, but still remained minimal offset.
Currently, I used addRectangle (), an overlapping shapes.
Thank you for your help.